# ASP Repeater Evals mixed with HTML

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, controls, repeater

I want to include HTML and Eval within a Repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Rpt" runat="server" DataSourceID="DS">
    <HeaderTemplate><div id="gallery"></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href='<%# Eval("Url") %>' class="show">  
            <img src='<%# Eval("Image") %>' alt='<%# Eval("Title") %>'
                title="" runat="server" id="sb1" rel='<%# Eval("Title") %>'/>
         </a>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I want the rel attribute Eval Title to have h3 tags wrapped around it. I've done this before, but I'm drawing a huge blank. My h3 tags look like this :( <h3>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I noticed is you need to end the `div` tag in your `FooterTemplate`:

```
<FooterTemplate></div></FooterTemplate>
```

Then get rid of your `runat="server"` tag if you don't need it because it will cause the tags in the `rel` attribute to get encoded:

```
<ItemTemplate> 
    <a href='<%# Eval("Url") %>' class="show">   
        <img src='<%# Eval("Title") %>' alt='<%# Eval("Title") %>' 
            title="" id="sb1" rel='<h3><%# Eval("Title") %></h3>'/> 
    </a> 
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: i had to change the url but that worked...any idea why now my jquery image scroller displays the first image TWICE then starts scrolling properly having just been placed in this repeater?

Comment: Not sure but did you make sure to put the `</div>` tag in your footer?

Comment: Yeah that was just a typo. Damn I can't use a repeater if its going to eff up the slideshow..i guess ill post a different question. Thanks

Comment: It really shouldn't be the repeater as it just outputs the html you are providing in the template and that is all that the jQuery is looking at.  There is something in the rendering or the jQuery slider that is incorrect.

Comment: Yeah I found out it was because of a class missing but needed to be added dynamically on the first item. ;)